# multiple controller parameters using xmlSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

Is there a way to pass multiple parameters to a web api controller using HttpClient.PostAsync and the XmlMediaTypeFormatter with UseXmlSerializer set to true?

I have the following controller which I am unable to reach:

```
public class itemController : ApiController {
    public void Post(string item1, string item2, string item3) {
        //manipulate items.
    }
}
```

I then call this with:

```
HttpClient client= GetClient();
StringWrapper wrapper = new StringWrapper{ Item1 = "1", Item2 = "2", Item3 = "3" };
await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/item", wrapper,
                 new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerialzer = true } );
```

If I duplicate the StringWrapper object on the host the client can call it but I'd rather not do this as the host and client are separate programs so I would rather the dependencies kept to a minimum.

I believe this can be done using the jsonSerializer, however I am required to use the XmlSerializer.

Cheers.